# Laravel Eloquent - Update Enum type

Tags: laravel, enums, laravel-4

I have an `enum` column in my table `Schedule`. I want to be update the column, but I cannot. My `type` consists of 3 options: `common, template, revision`.

This does NOT work. The process goes through fine, but the `type` does not change:

```
$schedule = Schedule::find($id);
$schedule->type = 'common';
$scehdule->save();

return $schedule;
```

But this DOES work:

```
$schedule = Schedule::find($id);
$schedule->fill(['type' => 'common']);
$scehdule->save();

return $schedule;
```

This also works:

```
$schedule = Schedule::find($id);
unset($schedule->type);
$schedule->type = 'common';
$scehdule->save();

return $schedule;
```

Problem is that I have validators that need to be satisfied if I were to use `fill()`. I only want to change one column, so I'd like to use the first approach.

Could someone advice?

Comment: Both methods use `setAttribute` to set its value, so I suppose your problem lies somewhere else. You have typos in the question, maybe you have some in the code? Also explain `does not work`

Comment: I mean the value of the `type` doesn't change. There are no errors, and everything goes through fine, but the old value is retained.

Comment: You have typos/errors in the question (type / task), maybe in your code there is some typo too. I can't think of anything else that would cause such error.

Comment: No, sorry the typo was only here, not in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Laravel 5.3. When you are using an enum in the database you can set the enum by using an integer. 1 = common, 2 = template, 3 = revision.

```
$schedule = Schedule::find($id);
$schedule->type = 1;
$scehdule->save();

return $schedule;
```

This will set the schedule type to "common"